# How to inheritance a window Form from another window Form in C#.Net

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to inheritance a window  form from another  window form in C#. Net, but got Errors

My First From

```
   public partial class Checkout : Form
{
    public Checkout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }
    


    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

> 2nd From Code to which i want to make inherited Form of First Form

```
public partial class OnwerPermission : Checkout
    {
        public OnwerPermission()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Got this error

[image]

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-inherit-windows-forms) says that you have to include the namespace of the base form when you inherit.

Comment: Bro still same error come

Comment: [This](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_inherited_forms.html) says the same thing.

Comment: What is the entire wording of that error message?

Comment: @RobertHarvey To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: 

The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: OnwerPermission --- The base class 'EPOS.Checkout' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

Comment: Have you built all the projects?

Comment: Yeah, Same Error........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing this:

1. Close all the UI design pages
2. Clean Solution
3. Rebuild Solution
4. Try to open your form again